# Need help identifying window balance type

Tags: windows

I have a house built in the 80's with, what I believe are, single pane double sliding up and down windows. The window slider is now difficult to open, and sometimes won't stay up at all. Does anybody know what kind of window [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0LrX.jpg) is and which parts I need to replace?

Comment: The pics I seen do not show the part that needs to be Id'd, The one shows 1 of the 2 latches that allow the window to be tilted out of the opening from the top into the room, the other looks like what may be the top anchor, but there is nothing else around it for context. If you can tilt the window out of the frame by raising it up maybe an inch or 2, pull the 2 catches in, that should let you tilt the window down 90 degrees and actually remove it from there. Then you can get a good shot of the ballast. It is very important if the window sash can tilt this way that is does go down 90 degree

Comment: Silicon spray can work miracles on sticky window.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out its a tilt window spiral balance.